# obtaining Apache PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - per request - connection and actual execution time

Tags: java, http, httprequest, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Apache 4.* HTTP Client and PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager for my application. I am interested in logging the per request time spent in obtaining a connection from Connection-Pool and the time spent in actual request execution.

Is there some way I can do this ?

I have already overridden PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager and I am overriding Connect(), releaseConnection() and requestConnection() methods to increment some counters.

I am not sure how to obtain the actual http Request here in order to clearly state that : "Request [request data] spent time [time value] in obtaining the connection and time [time value] in executing the request on the server."

Comment: Have you tried logging with the thread id?  The connection manager manages connections, not requests, so when the connection manager is doing it's thing (checking out or releasing) it doesn't, and shouldn't, know about any request details.  You could elsewhere log the request details with the thread id, and correlate it later?  You could also leverage the logging MDC to achieve this http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#mdc

Comment: I agree that connection pool manager shouldn't care about request details. Can I instead obtain these details by overriding execute() method in http client somehow?

Comment: Maybe, but I would caution against too much tight coupling.  Have you considered turning on pool logging?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring Boot, you could set the log level to DEBUG in the application.properties of your Java application

```
logging.level.org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager=DEBUG
```

That logs the details when the connection was requested, leased and released.

You can combine it with using Spring Sleuth for trace id logging https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-sleuth#overview

```
2023-01-19 02:54:38.869 'DEBUG [traceid=3247a65b81bfb99b]' 1 --- [      task-7908] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection request: [route: {s}->https://url][total available: 1; route allocated: 8 of 8; total allocated: 8 of 20]
2023-01-19 02:54:38.869 'DEBUG [traceid=3247a65b81bfb99b]' 1 --- [      task-7908] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection leased: [id: 6339][route: {s}->https://url][total available: 0; route allocated: 8 of 8; total allocated: 8 of 20]
2023-01-19 02:54:39.097 'DEBUG [traceid=3247a65b81bfb99b]' 1 --- [      task-7908] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection [id: 6339][route: {s}->https://url] can be kept alive indefinitely
2023-01-19 02:54:39.097 'DEBUG [traceid=3247a65b81bfb99b]' 1 --- [      task-7908] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection released: [id: 6339][route: {s}->https://url][total available: 1; route allocated: 8 of 8; total allocated: 8 of 20]
```